# What does the word 'piriful' exactly mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

In the fifth line of his poem, *A Draught of Sunshine*, Keats uses the term 'piriful':

> ...
> Instead of a piriful rummer,
> My wine overbrims a whole summer;
> My bowl is the sky,
> And I drink at my eye,
> Till I feel in the brain
> A Delphian pain -
> ...

I've tried looking the word up but to no avail.
Hoping to get some light shed on the meaning and etymology of the word.

Comment: Could it be a typo for *pitiful*?

Comment: It is a typo for 'pitiful', much repeated on the web.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a typographical error.

Comment: See the poem (without the typo) here: [1](http://web.uvic.ca/~pwak3/keats/poem_hence_burgendy_claret_and_port.html), [2](https://genius.com/amp/Dominick-argento-in-praise-of-apollo-lyrics), [3](http://metaphors.iath.virginia.edu/metaphors/16707)

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo. Here is a scan of a printed version.

[image]

[Scanned on Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=H1HWCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=%22Instead%20of%20a%20pitiful%20rummer,%20My%20wine%20overbrims%20a%20whole%20summer;%22&source=bl&ots=p6RCKPCnwh&sig=ACfU3U1Ocu4QuXuyGGe6X_y0zEs99GDxiA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS7Y-R0q_rAhUAVBUIHcckBDcQ6AEwBHoECA4QAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Instead%20of%20a%20pitiful%20rummer%2C%20My%20wine%20overbrims%20a%20whole%20summer%3B%22&f=false)